# How can I copy a certain range in a special way with VBA when a cell with a formula changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have used this code, but what happens is that the range gets copied and pasted multiple times and I end up with only the changed numbers.

thisworkbook code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
prevval = Sheet1.Range("O133").Value
End Sub
```

worksheet code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()


If Range("O133").Value <> prevval Then

    Call movetoleft
    prevval = Range("O133").Value


End If
End Sub

Private Sub movetoleft()
Range("C139:Q142").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B139").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, displayasicon:=False, iconfilename:=False

End Sub
```

module code

```
Public prevval As Variant
```

So the cells Q140, Q141 and Q142 include a formula that uses the value in O133 (this is a cell with a formula) - so I need this cells to have the value which takes into account (in any way) the change of value of O133. And all the rest have to be copied and pasted as values one place to the left of these (Q140, Q141 and Q142) cells. In the top cells of this range ( C139 to Q139) there are dates in the form of (5/31/2013, 6/30/2013, ... , 8/31/2014) and I want to forget about the 5/31/2013 (in cell C139) data and move all the rest one place to the left, so that after a change of O133 (because of the data for the new month- which in this example would be the data for September) we would have the the top cells change to 6/30/2013, 7/31/2013,..., 9/30/2014.

What happens with this particular code, is that  when the movetoleft sub is called due to the change of value in O133, it doesnt finish in the "end sub" but goes straight back to inside of if statement and repeats this multiple more times. At the end i finish with the data for (9/30/2014, 9/30/2014,..., 9/30/2014).

I would really appreciate your help. I find it really tiring doing these reports every month manually. That is why I decided to learn VBA and possibly also some other language.

Peace out

Aleš

Comment: things are a little bit unclear. Your O133 cell have a formula itself. When this cells value change, the other 3 cells also change. After you finished copying cells by 1 cell left shifted, what would be in the Q column? post a good screenshot of your sheet and clarify more if possible to get suggestive measure.

Comment: the Q column would reflect the new monthly data (in this case September). So e.g. the Q141=O133 is the formula for Q141 cell, so this cell in particular after pasting the range one place to the left, will have the newly changed value of O133. i cannot post pictures since this was my first post and I dont have a reputation of 10. Is it possible that I send you the screenshot in any other way?

Comment: you can upload to dropbox or sendspace or any similar free file storage area and post a link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvy1hg1jl0p44x2/Untitled.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited Code:**

Workbook Open:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
prevval = Sheet1.Range("O133").Value
MsgBox "At startup_prevval = " & prevval     'inactive like this : single quote before line start
End Sub
```

Worksheet Calculate:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
MsgBox "before calculate_prevval = " & prevval     'inactive like this : single quote before line
If Range("O133").Value <> prevval Then
'Call movetoleft
Call movetoleft2                           'call movetoleft or movetoleft2 : check which one works
prevval = Range("O133").Value
End If
MsgBox "after calculate_prevval = " & prevval      'inactive like this : single quote before line
End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Public prevval As Double   'it seems double is good for your current data

Sub movetoleft()
MsgBox "movetoleft is executing once"    'inactive like this : single quote before line
Range("C139:Q142").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B139").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, displayasicon:=False, iconfilename:=False
End Sub

Sub movetoleft2()
 MsgBox "movetoleft2 is executing once"    'inactive like this : single quote before line
 Range("C139:Q142").Copy
 Range("B139").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

[image: updated code]

Comment: Looks like the problem with Public prevval As Integer is that if any cell in the sheet changes it does the procedure.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jst2jush4y8koce/Untitled1.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr2tq0vadyr0qjl/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: what do you mean by "it does the procedure". is your problem solved?

Comment: the whole procedure. so when it copies and pastes the range it is noted as another change of value so it copies and pastes again ana again and again,... you can find the print screen in the untitled.png in dropbox. SO no my problem is not solved by your code. It makes it a little bit worse

Comment: it should not be so. I tried and tested this. See Appended images.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is noted another change of value". Worksheet_calculate happens when a cell with formula update its value. But this does not mean every time movetoleft is called. Use msgbox where you need to check if prevval is changing as it should be. See my appended images.

Comment: wtf. so strange. i have written everything like you said. Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: First, check workbook_open event to see if prevval is loaded at startup. Second, check calculate event. Third, check call movetoleft line. Do these three steps individually, not at the same time. You can comment code lines to make them inactive for testing and Msgbox is ideal for checking variable state in between code. Please be patient, otherwise it will make your problem worse.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but somehow i still cannot figure it out. im a complete beginner at this stage. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9eqp9yaacgxhj8n/AAAePtObl95p3fuJf6RTrwm_a?dl=0

Comment: upload your code window in 3 separate images, exactly same as mine 3 images above. Or, upload your file if possible, then i can see whats going wrong.

Comment: uploaded file worked as per your requirement. No problem found. by the way, Q139 date : how do you get it? there is no formula for this cell. see latest answer. changes are for you to debug. Another thing is you should be in the sheet1 while o133 value is changing.

Comment: i have figured it out. I have a TODAY() function on my worksheet (in the file that i have sent you, i have deleted some of the data - i just left the ones that i thought were relevant). And the file that I have sent you works just fine. So now i have explored which data that i have deleted causes the problem. And now I see if I delete the TODAY() function it works properly. So please add the TODAY() function and you will see this. But I need the date to update somehow. Do you have any idea how to get around this?

Comment: ok i got. no worries. really, thank you for everything. This helped my understanding of vba a lot. hope I see you around sometimes on the forum. peace out

Comment: If the answer helped you, then mark this as answer, See [Accept an Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or upvote it, See [When to Vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)